# Can I backup setting of shotcut keys on special characters in Ms-Office

Tags: backup, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office, special-characters

I am using Ms-Office 2007 and created some shortcut keys for special characters as shown below screen-shot:

[image]

Now My question is: Is there any way to backup this setting/configuration of shortcut keys (may be any configuration file in Ms-Office containing this setting information)? so-that I can backup it and can use (replace file) in future in case of re-installing Ms-Office or in case of copy setting to another PC's Ms-Office (same version & font & Unicode)?

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

copy the file "Normal.dotm" from this path:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates
```

and paste it to the same path in the new computer.

this file holds not only your custom keyboard shortcuts but also custom toolbars, macros and styles.